# Codeigniter - Running Cron without Cron Tab

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl, cron, command-line-interface

Trying to figure out how to run a cron without using Cron Tab. I have my app setup on a shared hosting (client) of which has an Admin UI method for doing Cron Jobs. It's asking for path to a PHP file and won't let me write a controller or method after the file. See following image.

[image]

Here are their docs on what's possible:

https://docs.ovh.com/fr/fr/web/hosting/mutualise-taches-automatisees-cron/

On my dev server I am using Cron Tab and line looks like this:

`0 8 * * * curl http://<site_here>/crons/<function_name>/`

How should I fill out the `Command to be executed line`? Should I move my function to `index` or call it from the `__construct` if that's even a possibility (or wise)?

Comment: As per in your scenario you might consider using https://packagist.org/packages/lavary/crunz which lets you set cron  and do everything using php and without cron tab.

Comment: @MASIDDIQUIis there another option without having to install anything new on the server?